# Creating a windows installer for python application (converted to .exe) which creates shortcuts in desired directories

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-installer, background-task

I want to create a windows installer for my application which is already converted to a exe via pyinstaller. This installer should be able to write a shortcut to the desktop and to `C:\Users\(myuser)\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`. Till now, I have only been able to find solutions for the desktop shortcuts but not for the desired location.

PS: My aim in this is to keep it as user-friendly as possible. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Does anyone know the answer to this or is it impossible to achieve it?